# Troubling uploading file from (coldfusion) server into sharepoint with Rest

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest, file-upload, server

Sharepoint is giving me this message which I can't interpret.

> "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":
>   {...see below...}" is not valid."}}}"

URL: https://{entitychanged}.sharepoint.com/{siteChanged}/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('{siteChanged}/#arguments.libraryPath#/#arguments.folderName#')/Files/add(url='#arguments.filename#';overwrite=true;)/@TargetFileName='#arguments.filename#'

Error: {"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The expression \"Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/{siteChanged}/{folder name(with space, not %20)}/C88-8888')/Files/add(url='Budget C88-8888.xlsm';overwrite=true;)/@TargetFileName='Budget C88-8888.xlsm'\" is not valid."}}} 
I have tried a number of 'urls':

> {... []_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/path/part/item/foldername/C88-8888')/Files/add(url='Budget%20C88-8888.xlsm';overwrite=true;) ...}
>
> {... [] _api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/path/part/item/foldername')/Files/add(overwrite=true;url='/sites/path/part/item/foldername/#arguments.filename#')/?@TargetLibrary='#arguments.libraryPath#'@TargetFileName='#arguments.filename#'"; ...}

and various versions, including the line immediately above with 'filename')?@TargetLibrary   (The / present or not)

I am using :

- Accept: application/json; odata=verbose
- content-type: application/xml
- header=binaryStringRequestBody
- I am using the Digest
- I am using the content length, access token, and digests.
- posting x-http-methods PUT and POST.
- body of: binary and toBase64(binary)

The target structure is [site]/{Library}/{Folder}/(Adding file here)

I am having success with getMetaData, @value for content, but for the life of me I can't figure out why the uploading of files is being rejected.

I noticed that the last step had spaces in the url, using URLEncodedFormat() to replace spaces with %20 did NOT resolve the issue.
G

Comment: Can you post what is the error message which I see you excluded? I am talking about the text between the curly brackets: `"message": {...} is not valid.`

Comment: I included several examples right below the error message. I get the same message for each of the items between the brackets. I removed the first part of the url to protect my employer. Thanks.   \n<br /> I am getting most things, its just the post/putting of files that I am having trouble with getting it to work.

Comment: Ok, I was able to use basically the same code as above to upload/attach an Excel file to a List/List Item. So why does upload work for lists but not folders. (Obviously I had to use /Lists/Items(1)/AttachmentFiles/Add)

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like I was doing a few things wrong.

The ColdFusion language I use passes arguments as a structure, the order does not matter. This appears to not be the case for Sharepoint. 
ex: 
files/add(overwrite=true,url='#arguments.filename#')
            is not the same as
files/add( url='#arguments.filename#'; overwrite=true; )

I also had [;] semicolons where I needed [,] commas.

All extraneous spaces need to be removed, other spaces need [%20] encoding.
Dashes and underlines if encoded show up encoded, wrong. just replace spaces.

I hope this helps someone else.